# Theme and line number for Codemirror doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, codemirror

I can't get CodeMirror to set the theme to what i set it to.

folow the document at [Codemirror Manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) I've done this:

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="Styles/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Styles/elegant.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            mode: "text/x-csharp",
            theme: "Styles/elegant.css"
            });

    </script> 
</head>
```

I have tried many ways now, but i don't get how to, so i am asking for 
help.

There is no theme, syntax highlighting or lineNumber in the editor when i try it. 
I hope someone can explain this to me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `theme` option incorrectly. In this case, set it to `"elegant"`. The problem is caused by CodeMirror setting the CSS class of the editor (which is used to select a theme) to some filename bogus when you pass a filename there, which'll prevent the highlighting from working.